# Django. Using .ini files in code folder

Tags: python, django, heroku, settings

I wanted to have a .py file using a ConfigParser class to recover information from a .ini file (containing URLs for a 3rd party REST service) Until now this worked since it was finding the file, but now it's not. App structure is:

```
app
    folder
        file.py
        urls.ini
```

I assume this is due to my static files settings, which are as following:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

This is because I wanted to mantain settings that were compatible for both local development and web production escenarios (for which I could probably test with code in the web) for Heroku. I wanted to make it so I didn't have to change much stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to read some files, you have to get the route.

If you have your static folder in your Django folder it could be easy to get your .ini file doing this

```
ini = open("%s/folder/yourfile.ini" % BASE_DIR, "r")
```

And then read your file lines.

In my opinion using a .py file for configuration it's easier than .ini file, and you can have many of them and load depending of a settings.py parameter for example.

Edit: for using Django config file variables

```
from django.conf import settings
BASE_DIR = settings.BASE_DIR
```

Comment: But I have no access to BASE_DIR because that's a variable in the settings.py file provided by Django. Which is in the top level of thehierarchy that I'm not supposed to access, and I'm like 3 levels below.

My problem might be of where is the ini file when Django deploys, which I don't know

Comment: I see, you can access to the Django settings if you want using:

`from django.conf import settings`

Also you can "replicate" that "BASE_DIR" variable using the following code:

`import os`
`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: Apologize if I'm wrong here, but `"__file__"` would make the path go all the way down to my ini file, which I don't want, right? I want to make sure I'm at the top level. The suggestion about using "django.conf" works like a charm, though, so thanks! I wanted to tag your answer as correct, but can you add the part of importing settings for other people? If you think that's ok

Comment: I gotta ask: why use settings to find settings? Why not just add a tuple to settings.py? Is this `.ini` file provided by 3rd party?

Comment: Because until now I didn't know you could just import settings, I figured that file was solely for Django config stuff, not also for storing your own stuff. This file is my own.